# (JS) Auto Create for each JSON Array Name/ Id/ Key) in .json File > a DIV or BUTTON (Li) with it's JSON Array Name

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, key

)

I want that my JS create automatic for each JSON Array (name) inside the JSON File > a link with it's name in my HTML File.

For Single Arrays it works fine with the [Number] , but all with the correct name assignment doesn't work (alert throws all yes).

I hope someone knows how?

Thanks Dudes!

**Javascript:**

```
// ----- JS ------ //
$.getJSON("json/some.json", function(data) {
    $.each([data], function(i, data) {
        var data_create_link = "<li><a href='#'><button>1 - "+(Object.keys(data)[0])+"</button></a></li>";

        $(data_create_link).appendTo("#div");
    });

    //alert(Object.keys(data)); /* Alert all Names (work) */
});
```

**JSON:**

*File: some.json blabla*

```
// ----- JSON ------ //
{
    "Queen":[
        {
            "blabla": "who am i:",
            "bla": "who are you :)"
        }
    ],
    "Depeche":[
        {
            "blabla": "is it's me?",
            "bla": "grrrrrrr :)"
        }
    ],
    "Tiga":[
        {
            "blabla": "Watttt ?",
            "bla": "L ö L"
        }
    ]
}

// -------------------------- End ---------------------------- //
```

Comment: Array name ( Queen, Depeche, Tiga .... )

Comment: Please define "_doesn't work_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for in loop.

```
$.getJSON("json/some.json",function(data){
  for(var prop in data){
    var data_create_link = "<li><a href='#'><button>1 - "+prop+"</button></a>";
    $(data_create_link).appendTo("#div");
  }
});
```

for in iterates over all properties of an object. If you want to read the properties value you could use `data[prop]`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in for further reference.

Comment: Please upvote and mark as answer then please :) You're welcome

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery here is the proper jQuery code:

```
    $.each(data, function(key, value){

        var link = $('<a></a>')
            .prop('href', '#')
            .html(key)
        ;

        $('<li></li>')
            .html(link)
            .appendTo('#div')
        ;
    });
```

Here is the working example

```js
var data = {
  'id': 2,
  'number': 3
};

$.each(data, function(key, value) {

  var link = $('<a></a>')
    .prop('href', '#')
    .html(key);

  $('<li></li>')
    .html(link)
    .appendTo('ul');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul></ul>
```